# How to stretch the image size in iphone UIImage or UIImageView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'd like to show an image in an iPhone app, but the image I'm using is too big. 
I'd like to scale it to fit the iPhone screen, I can't find any class to handle it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
UIImageView* view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"your_image.png"]];
view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
```

To get the frame of the iPhone screen you can use

```
CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

Answer (score 17):

In Interface Builder, select your UIImageView. From the Tools menu, select "Attribute Inspector". In the Image View Attributes palette, select "Scale to Fill" from the Mode popup. That should scale your image to fit.

Comment: how to program with code to achieve effect of "Scale to Fill" ?

Comment: Get it ! imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

Answer (score 0):

My ImageView was set in IB, and I would need to show multiple images, so set the image of imageView, instead of creating ImageView for individual image.

After I set the image view frame size, I am still see the same result, the image was too big, so that only part of the image was displayed on the screen.